# How to vertically align a paragraph next to a button

Tags: bootstrap-5

Beginner question about bootstrap, i just cant get a solution for this problem!

I want to have both the 'Send' and 'Problem in Sending Mail' text on the same line.

Code:

```
<div class="d-inline-flex">
    <button class="btn" name="submit" onClick="sendContact();">Send</button>
    <p class="">Problem in Sending Mail.</p>
</div>
```

Whatever i do, the 'Problem in Sending Mail' text is always at the top of the div space.

[image]

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `align-items: flex-end` ?

```
<div class="d-inline-flex align-items-end">
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#align-items

[image]

Comment: align-items-baseline worked for me ^^

Comment: nice! flex box is a little confusing at first, but i rely on it all the time now because it is so useful - I suggest this resource to quickly refer to whenever you need it: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/